# Convert HTML div to image in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to pass an url from my jsp page. It should parse that page, fetch a specific div of html and convert div output in to a image and display it on my page.

Example: I pass www.google.com and output of div i want to convert in image is

I got a good jQuery for the same "http://codepedia.info/convert-html-to-image-in-jquery-div-or-table-to-jpg-png/" but its working on local page only not allowing to pass a URL

can anyone help in this matter.

Comment: try an iframe inside the div that you are trying to convert to canvas.  Keep in mind with google.com, if you are looking for results you will need to include the search query in the url,  this may mean using special characters in your iframe src field.

Comment: I agree with Danimal

Answer (score 7):

> @Pushkar Sharan you can do this with html2canvas just add some script
>   like jquery-ui.css, jquery.js, jquery-ui.js,
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js
>   then try to understand below code

```
<html>
    <head>
      <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
      <script>
          $(window).load(function(){
           $('#load').click(function(){ //calling this function when Save button pressed
              html2canvas($('#cont'), {//give the div id whose image you want in my case this is #cont
              onrendered: function (canvas) {
              var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png",1.0);//here set the image extension and now image data is in var img that will send by our ajax call to our api or server site page


              $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "http://localhost/my/index.php",//path to send this image data to the server site api or file where we will get this data and convert it into a file by base64
                    data:{
                      "img":img
                    },
                    success:function(data){
                    $("#dis").html(data);
                    }
              });
              }
              });
          });
        });
      </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="cont"> 

      </div><br>
      <center><input type="button" value="Save" id="load"></center><br>
      <div id="dis"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now server site program suppose this is index.php so

> index.php

```
    <?php
    $img = $_POST['img'];//getting post img data
            $img = substr(explode(";",$img)[1], 7);//converting the data 
            $target=time().'img.png';//making file name
            file_put_contents('uploads/'.$target, base64_decode($img));//converting the $img with base64 and putting the image data in uploads/$target file name  
//now just check in your upload folder you will get your html div image in that folder
    ?>
```