# html2canvas drawImage() to base64, img is compressed

Tags: javascript, php

My English is not very good, is translated by Google：
I was doing a phone-side pages, the demand is: on a template image, the user can input information in the input box, and then I passed HTML2canvas plug-page screen shots, and then share the picture out. Because the company can not put my picture publishing platform, so this template picture on my personal server, image link address is www.myself.com/aa.png. Then I did the link address of the page is www.gongsi.com/index.html. Then with canvas screen shots when across domain image screen shots will not be displayed, so I was in I wrote a php server interfaces, the picture transmitted to the front end by 64 yards:

```
$file="../img/p6.png";  
$type=getimagesize($file);
$fp=fopen($file,"r")or die("Can't open file");  
$file_content=chunk_split(base64_encode(fread($fp,filesize($file))));//base64  
switch($type[2]){ 
case 1:$img_type="gif";break;  
case 2:$img_type="jpg";break;  
case 3:$img_type="png";break;  
}  
$img='data:image/'.$img_type.';base64,'.$file_content; 
fclose($fp); 
echo $_GET['callback'] . "(" . json_encode(array('img' => $img)) . ")";
```

front end receiving the tip directly set the src attribute of the img tag:

```
imgDiv.setAttribute("src", data.img);
```

src attribute of the img tag this time is a pile of 64 yards, the picture can be displayed, and then HTML2canvas screenshots:

```
html2canvas(screen,
                {    
                    width:$(".capture_screen").width(),
                    height:$(".capture_screen").height(),
                    canvas:canvas,
                    onrendered:function(canvas){    
                            sendImg(canvas.toDataURL());    //send base64 to my server                                            
                    }                                
                })
```

Then the back-end php code is received:

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', '../images/');
    $img = $_POST['img'];

    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    if($success)
    {
        $imgStatus = 1;
        echo json_encode(array('status' => '1', 'imgStatus' => $imgStatus, 'img' => $file)); //存储成功    
    }
    else
    {
        $imgStatus = -1;
        echo json_encode(array('status' => '-1', 'msg' => '存储失败')); //存储失败
    }
```

So that the entire process is over, the picture on the server and then uploaded by users, some normal, some pictures are compressed:
[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV4s2.png)[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btkiv.png)

I would like to ask: Where is the image compression problem?

Comment: ultimately you want to get image by html2canvas?

Comment: am i right @Sam without compressing ?

Comment: yes,I want to use html2canvas get a new image by user write input box

Comment: please refer it from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745988/convert-html-div-to-image-in-jquery/38746703#38746703